# Resample & calculate mean

Tags: python, pandas, mean, pandas-resample

Working with pandas in Python.

My data looks like:

```
2018-03-16    5.0
2018-03-17    5.0
2018-03-18    5.0
...
2018-03-31    5.0
```

After using

```
resample('MS').mean()
```

I get the following result:

```
2018-03-01     5.000000
```

The correct result should be approximately 2.5 instead of 5. The **resample** method simply calculates the mean from the first given day within the month instead of taking into account the previous days where value was **0**. This problem is even more absurd when e.g. calculating yearly mean you could have a time series starting on Dec 31th and resample would give **x** instead of **x/365**.

Surely, there must be a better solution than filling missing initial dates with zeroes? Is there a parameter that could take care of this problem?

I should add that I'm primarily interested in solutions that involve resample, e.g. if there is a simple way to fix this with setting up a parameter. If not, I will settle for a solution that does not involve the resample method. So, I am also open to suggestions using methods other than **resample**.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try `groupby` and `apply`

```py
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

out = (df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%Y-%m'))
       .apply(lambda g: g['val'].sum()/pd.Period(g.name).days_in_month)
# or
#      .apply(lambda g: g['val'].sum()/pd.to_datetime(g.name).days_in_month)
       .to_frame('val'))
```

```
print(out)

              val
2018-03  0.645161
```

Comment: Looks promising!